# Copy folder and subfolder by filter PS

Tags: powershell, filter, copy, subdirectory

I've been trying for a while and still haven't got the solution
Can anyone help me with a Powershell script to go over all the folders inside a path and copy all the subfolders with specific name
for example: C:\Clients -is the main folder and under it I have many clients names and subfolders
I would like for each client inside the clients folder to copy the Proposals folder
and so I will have a new C:\Test\Clients*Clientname\Proposal...

what I have so far is:

```
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\tst' -Name)
foreach ($i in $Files){
    $names= "C:\tst\$i"
    Write-Host $names
Copy-Item -Path $names -Destination "C:\tst2" -Recurse
```

I'm missing the Filter part

Comment: It would help if you first read [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)..

Comment: Does this list the folders you want to copy?  `Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Clients -Filter Proposals -Directory -Recurse | select FullName`